# Simulate history.go(-1) with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, href

I have three different html files (**page1.html**, **page2.html**, **page3.html**) that each contain a link to the same target in a fourth html file (**glossary.html**).

For technical reasons, I can't use **history.go(-1)** or other brower-specific functions, but I can use JavaScript and JavaScript libraries, e.g. JQuery, and LocalStorage.

What would be the best way to mimic the functionality of **history.go(-1)** with JavaScript?

The technical details are as follows:

**page1.html** contains the following link:

```
<a id="page1" href="glossary.html#def1" class="footnote">1</a>
```

**page2.html** contains the following link:

```
<a id="page2" href="glossary.html#def1" class="footnote">1</a>
```

**page3.html** contains the following link:

```
<a id="page3" href="glossary.html#def1" class="footnote">1</a>
```

**glossary.html** contains the following link:

```
<a id="fn1" href="#">↵ Back </a>Term 1: Definition of term one.
```

I.e., the script(s) should do the following:

1. Retrieve the id of the calling html page (**page1**, **page2** or **page3**) and save it as a LocalStorage item or in another suitable persistent manner.
2. When the user clicks the **↵ Go back** link, the href of the definition in glossary.html needs to be updated so that it points to **page1.html#page1**, **page2.html#page2** or **page3.html#page3**, depending on the html page that the glossary link was clicked on.

What would be the easiest way to solve this problem?

Comment: *"For technical reasons, I can't use history.go(-1) or other brower-specific functions"* We'll need to know more about that restriction, since it doesn't make much sense. Just about any answer is going to use "browser-specific functions" (or objects) like `location`. Note that your "should do the following" uses browser-specific things like local storage.

Comment: Another posible solution could be insert query string parameters in your url or hash property and parse it on page load. i.e. /glosary.html?back_url=...

Comment: the only thing I can think of is to store the routes on a local storage and navigate through them! but as @T.J.Crowder said it is another browser-specific thing

Comment: I DISAGREE the HOLD status on this question. In 2 out of 3 comments above, people like  @T.J. Crowder (450 894 rep. points) and  Amin Jafari (4 639 rep. points) where talking about `localStorage`. **Question WAS clear.**

Comment: About cross-browser compatibilty... I don't know your fears... It looks like to be supported for a while. [REF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: The local storage part was clear (the OP specifically talked about using local storage). What wasn't, and isn't, clear is how they expect to use that information without using "...other brow[s]er-specific functions". The unclear part is what, exactly, browser features they cannot use, so we can point them in the right direction -- the `location` object, `querySelector` and setting `href`, etc. That said, they *did* say they could use jQuery... But jQuery relies on browser-specific features, so...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Maybe... But for commons of the mortals... You really didn't have a clue to show him the way? **Maybe** he doesn't know about php... What if, with an answer, he realise it's time to explore it? For sure, the question was clear if you get rid of the no "...other brower [sic] features" part.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: It's usually a waste of time to try to answer a question with a minefield (the things the OP can't use that they haven't told us about). The OP can come back, add the necessary information, and get the question reopened. Or delete the question and post one with all the necessary information. Then we can help. That's how things work here. I have voted to reopen, since they said they can use jQuery and there is a jQuery+localStorage solution, so hopefully that steers between the mines... :-)

Comment: Thanks. On my point of view, I think that the title AND the text of the question is clear enought to lead some future readers straith to localStorage. Then, mission accomplished, it's not a waste of time *in this case*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) in your `glossary.html` to record the referer url.

You can get it easily if you use a server-side script like PHP with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`...
Then pass it to Javascript by echoing it in a variable.

```
urlValue="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>";
localStorage.setItem("referer", urlValue);    // name, value
```

The rest of the coding adventure is up to you.
;)

Comment: Thanks for the only helpful answer! 
That was exactly what I was looking for.
The rest I can do myself.